ValueError: Unknown layer: 'GetItem'
Here is the full error message:

ValueError: Unknown layer: 'GetItem'. Please ensure you are using a keras.utils.custom_object_scope and that this object is included in the scope. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.

The problem I am having here is that this GetItem layer is preventing me from loading my model. The GetItem layer comes from indexing the Keras input layer. The original input layer shape is (None, 256, 33), and this shape is split into (None, 256, 1) and (None, 256, 32), the former of which gets sliced to (None, 1) and the latter of which transform into (None, 8) after tensor operations.
Because this layer is not a handmade custom layer by me but instead the result of tensor indexing, I have no idea how to pass the layer class like model = load_model('my_model.h5', custom_objects={'GetItem': GetItem}).
Thus, I need help in either passing the GetItem layer as a custom layer to the load_model function or loading the model without this hassle.
(My Tensorflow version is 2.17.0, and Keras version is 3.5.0.)
Here is the code I used to load the model.
import os

import tensorflow as tf

parent_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Model')
file_name = "2024_08_14_yunja_Cylinder_MDN_1.h5"
file_path = os.path.join(parent_path, file_name)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(file_path)

Here is the shape of the model architecture.
┌─────────────────────┬───────────────────┬────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ Layer (type)        │ Output Shape      │    Param # │ Connected to      │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ input_layer         │ (None, 256, 33)   │          0 │ -                 │
│ (InputLayer)        │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ get_item_1          │ (None, 256, 32)   │          0 │ input_layer[0][0] │
│ (GetItem)           │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ gaussian_noise      │ (None, 256, 32)   │          0 │ get_item_1[0][0]  │
│ (GaussianNoise)     │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv1d (Conv1D)     │ (None, 256, 64)   │     18,496 │ gaussian_noise[0… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv1d_1 (Conv1D)   │ (None, 256, 64)   │     10,304 │ gaussian_noise[0… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ concatenate         │ (None, 256, 128)  │          0 │ conv1d[0][0],     │
│ (Concatenate)       │                   │            │ conv1d_1[0][0]    │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv1d_2 (Conv1D)   │ (None, 128, 64)   │     41,024 │ concatenate[0][0] │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ max_pooling1d       │ (None, 128, 128)  │          0 │ concatenate[0][0] │
│ (MaxPooling1D)      │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ concatenate_1       │ (None, 128, 192)  │          0 │ conv1d_2[0][0],   │
│ (Concatenate)       │                   │            │ max_pooling1d[0]… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv1d_3 (Conv1D)   │ (None, 128, 32)   │     43,040 │ concatenate_1[0]… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv1d_4 (Conv1D)   │ (None, 128, 32)   │     30,752 │ concatenate_1[0]… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ concatenate_2       │ (None, 128, 64)   │          0 │ conv1d_3[0][0],   │
│ (Concatenate)       │                   │            │ conv1d_4[0][0]    │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv1d_5 (Conv1D)   │ (None, 64, 32)    │     10,272 │ concatenate_2[0]… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ max_pooling1d_1     │ (None, 64, 64)    │          0 │ concatenate_2[0]… │
│ (MaxPooling1D)      │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ concatenate_3       │ (None, 64, 96)    │          0 │ conv1d_5[0][0],   │
│ (Concatenate)       │                   │            │ max_pooling1d_1[… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv1d_6 (Conv1D)   │ (None, 64, 32)    │     15,392 │ concatenate_3[0]… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv1d_7 (Conv1D)   │ (None, 64, 32)    │      9,248 │ concatenate_3[0]… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ concatenate_4       │ (None, 64, 64)    │          0 │ conv1d_6[0][0],   │
│ (Concatenate)       │                   │            │ conv1d_7[0][0]    │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv1d_8 (Conv1D)   │ (None, 32, 32)    │     10,272 │ concatenate_4[0]… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ re_lu (ReLU)        │ (None, 32, 32)    │          0 │ conv1d_8[0][0]    │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ max_pooling1d_2     │ (None, 32, 64)    │          0 │ concatenate_4[0]… │
│ (MaxPooling1D)      │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ concatenate_5       │ (None, 32, 96)    │          0 │ re_lu[0][0],      │
│ (Concatenate)       │                   │            │ max_pooling1d_2[… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ flatten (Flatten)   │ (None, 3072)      │          0 │ concatenate_5[0]… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dropout (Dropout)   │ (None, 3072)      │          0 │ flatten[0][0]     │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ gaussian_noise_1    │ (None, 3072)      │          0 │ dropout[0][0]     │
│ (GaussianNoise)     │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dense (Dense)       │ (None, 1536)      │  4,720,128 │ gaussian_noise_1… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dropout_1 (Dropout) │ (None, 1536)      │          0 │ dense[0][0]       │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ gaussian_noise_2    │ (None, 1536)      │          0 │ dropout_1[0][0]   │
│ (GaussianNoise)     │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dense_1 (Dense)     │ (None, 256)       │    393,472 │ gaussian_noise_2… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dropout_2 (Dropout) │ (None, 256)       │          0 │ dense_1[0][0]     │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ gaussian_noise_3    │ (None, 256)       │          0 │ dropout_2[0][0]   │
│ (GaussianNoise)     │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dense_2 (Dense)     │ (None, 64)        │     16,448 │ gaussian_noise_3… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dense_3 (Dense)     │ (None, 8)         │        520 │ dense_2[0][0]     │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ get_item (GetItem)  │ (None, 1)         │          0 │ input_layer[0][0] │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ concatenate_6       │ (None, 9)         │          0 │ dense_3[0][0],    │
│ (Concatenate)       │                   │            │ get_item[0][0]    │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dense_4 (Dense)     │ (None, 4)         │         40 │ concatenate_6[0]… │
└─────────────────────┴───────────────────┴────────────┴───────────────────┘

Code for building the model:
def build_MGNN(
    input_shape: tuple[int], 
    output_num: int, 
    num_given: int, 
    last_activation: float
) -> tf.keras.models:
    
    input_ = Input(shape=input_shape)
    extra_ = input_[:, 0, :num_given]
    next_ = input_[:, :, num_given:]
    
    next_ = GaussianNoise(0.025)(next_)
    
    temp_0 = Conv1D(
        filters=64, 
        kernel_size=9, 
        strides=1, 
        padding="same", 
        activation="relu"
    )(next_)
        
    temp_1 = Conv1D(
        filters=64, 
        kernel_size=5, 
        strides=1, 
        padding="same", 
        activation="relu"
    )(next_)
        
    x = Concatenate(axis=2)([temp_0, temp_1])
    
    temp_0 = Conv1D(
        filters=64, 
        kernel_size=5,
        strides=2, 
        padding="same", 
        activation="relu"
    )(x)
        
    temp_1 = MaxPooling1D()(x)
    
    x = Concatenate(axis=2)([temp_0, temp_1])
    
    temp_0 = Conv1D(
        filters=32, 
        kernel_size=7, 
        strides=1, 
        padding="same", 
        activation="relu"
    )(x)
        
    temp_1 = Conv1D(
        filters=32, 
        kernel_size=5, 
        strides=1, 
        padding="same", 
        activation="relu"
    )(x)
        
    x = Concatenate(axis=2)([temp_0, temp_1])
    
    temp_0 = Conv1D(
        filters=32, 
        kernel_size=5, 
        strides=2, 
        padding="same", 
        activation="relu"
    )(x)
        
    temp_1 = MaxPooling1D()(x)
    
    x = Concatenate(axis=2)([temp_0, temp_1])
    
    temp_0 = Conv1D(
        filters=32, 
        kernel_size=5, 
        strides=1, 
        padding="same", 
        activation="relu"
    )(x)
        
    temp_1 = Conv1D(
        filters=32, 
        kernel_size=3, 
        strides=1, 
        padding="same", 
        activation="relu"
    )(x)
        
    x = Concatenate(axis=2)([temp_0, temp_1])
    
    temp_0 = Conv1D(
        filters=32, 
        kernel_size=5, 
        strides=2, 
        padding="same"
    )(x)
    
    temp_0 = ReLU()(temp_0)
    
    temp_1 = MaxPooling1D()(x)
    
    x = Concatenate(axis=2)([temp_0, temp_1])
    
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
    x = GaussianNoise(0.05)(x)
    
    x = Dense(units=1536, activation="relu")(x)
    
    x = Dropout(0.125)(x)
    x = GaussianNoise(0.025)(x)
    
    x = Dense(units=256, activation="relu")(x)
    
    x = Dropout(0.0625)(x)
    x = GaussianNoise(0.0125)(x)
    
    x = Dense(units=64, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dense(units=8, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Concatenate(axis=1)([x, extra_])
    x = Dense(units=2*output_num, activation=last_activation)(x)
        
    model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=x)
    
    return model


What code did you use to build this model?

@Dr.Snoopy I added the code I used.
